# How to Update value of spark dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe

```
        df = spark.createDataFrame([('Andy', 'NY'), ('Bob', 'PA'), ('Cindy', 'DC')], ("FName","City "))
```

Here I am trying to create a new dataframe with encrypted Fname column
PGP encryption function below takes string as input and give encryted string as output.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Customer")

for line in spark.table("Customer").collect():
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    gpg.import_keys('/home/keys/key.txt')
    encry_str=gpg.encrypt(line.FName, 'recipientid', passphrase='passphrase', always_trust=True)
    print(encry_str)
```

Encrypted string looks like this :

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

hQEMAyBWi2alDMW+AQf5AQn4VdbVNEHMWKzXUFRUyW+m1vepxbN//ENHw0F3dzvd
NAldsgZzpCv5pPq4QLYFw4Sq0eWqOK6Ezg4VxvBIB1l5J4cGsx7kMX9sfCU8T7Be
xqF1ZtWoTOqHp/cwt5NQFi+D302kRfUjUooszOl1zHOp9uOP12WEa/eInoCGRza1
z+73TQ1/0lxieuVVsJu4CsQhEDG9atk+rD21sRsfsOEIAzgIaXyBekZJ0zaiLJCe
LSqum0HebBrl5VJ5yozoAlDAIt0+oXsG2JwqsWpoQFKkuQFsqYGJ61k1+nX/st7i
WWKUvWtjb1ABp3XhC+nT8LpZYCNGIkx0wxQCqcsjjNI/AVjRHvbZsrCfZpua+vdJ
Vv/i1ZKfq0r/FPKgspHdCtMx2/ZAEmVZ3paHM/RGuFm82ihQhXkT78Ik//EiZD5D
=mRs6
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Expected output

```
+-----+-----+--------------------+
|FName|City |           Encrypted|
+-----+-----+--------------------+
| Andy|   NY|-----BEGIN PGP ME...|
|  Bob|   PA|-----BEGIN PGP ME...|
|Cindy|   DC|-----BEGIN PGP ME...| 
+-----+-----+--------------------+
```

I am trying to update the FName column, but getting exception

```
line.FName=gpg.encrypt(line.FName, 'recipientid', passphrase='passphrase', always_trust=True)
```

Exception: Row is read-only

How in the above frame work , I can Add/update encrypted string values to corresponding Dataframe columns ?

Answer (score 2):

You should think of Spark dataframes and RDDs as references/recipes to the underlying data. Therefore, if you really want to *change* the data, you need to first transform and then update/overwrite the existing data.

#### To transform:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

def mapper(row):
    # if row doesn't need updating, return original
    if row['my_test_column'] != 'some_test_value':
        return row

    row = row.asDict()
    row['updated_column'] = some_function(row['some_column'], ...)

    return Row(**row)
```

#### To save:

```
df_updated.write.saveAsTable('my_schema.my_new_table')
```

#### To update/overwrite:

```
df_updated.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('my_schema.my_table')
```

Comment: Hi Kris , I didnt get your point .  If i try with with reference to your code                     
   def mapper(row):
    ...:     row = row.asDict()
    ...:     row['FName'] = 'Andy'
    ...:     row['Enc'] = 'test'
    ...:     return Row(**row)

Comment: Okay, how could I clarify? What's the part that I'm not explaining right?

Comment: I tried your code,  and if i see df_updated.show(), its updating entire dataframe column ,                                                                                                            
     +-----+----+-----+
|City | Enc|FName|
+-----+----+-----+
|   NY|test| Andy|
|   PA|test| Andy|
|   DC|test| Andy|
+-----+----+-----+                                                                                                 
Where as I am trying to create a new dataframe which will have corresponding encryted string

Comment: Did you implement the logic of your `gpg.encrypt(...)` in your mapper?

Comment: For simplicity , I have used your mapper as shown below : and this is updating entire dataframe column of Fname to 'Andy'                                                                                    def mapper(row):
    ...:     row = row.asDict()
    ...:     row['FName'] = 'Andy'
    ...:     row['Enc'] = 'test'
    ...:     return Row(**row)

Comment: I see. You do need to implement your logic to the mapper. The mapper I showed was just an example. I'll update it. I hope that will clarify what I meant.

Comment: Assume : my_specific_function returns 'test1' . for row one of the dataframe , then as per your code , it will update 'test1' to all the rows of the new column . But what I am trying to achieve is for row1 of the data frame I should have new_column as 'test1' . And for row2 assume my_specific_function returns 'exam1' , then it should only be updated to row2  and so on . Its row-wise update I am looking for .